# Magento API performance issues when doing bulk product updates

Tags: magento

I am experiencing some performance issues with the Magento API. 
Basically I use the API to create and update products. It's integrated with the clients stock system. 
The first few products take 6 seconds or so.
After 10 mins, it takes around 15 seconds per product. 
It gets exponentially worse until it takes around 10 minutes per product.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

I was wanting to try writing to a log file the start and end time of each API request and what that request is. Hoping this would give me some more solid information to go on and if there's any pattern. wondered if someone might be able to point me to the best place to place my Mage:log() command(s).

I'm using Magento 1.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be of use.  There can be a lot of factors in a client bulk uploading products, and it's best to sense-check how they're using the API web services.

I wrote this to snoop what's actually going on.  It's been very useful so far in identifying client-side bugs in their SOAP calls.

http://techcolin.net/2011/11/a-php-proxy-script-for-logging-magento-api-soap-calls/

Hope this gives you some insight.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Your script helped me solve it. For the benefit of anyone else experiencing similar issues, I would reccommend this approach. Basically this gives you a new SOAP API, which you get your client to target instead of the normal Magento one. It logs every request from the client before passing it onto the proper Magento SOAP API. All responses are then also logged. A quick browse through the log files identified our issue in minutes - some badly generated SOAP calls from the client.

Answer (score 2):

[magmi](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi)

is a free , powerful & effective solution for catalog updates.

it worth the try, you can find the documentation [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi)

Answer (score 2):

Main reason, why it is slower and slower are indexes. Go to Index management and set mode of indexes to manual. After bulk update, reindex all indexes from the admin or from the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth noting, enabling cache in the Magento Admin provides an enormous performance boost to the API calls.