# Magento API error: Invalid data given. Details in error message. - Where is this "error message"?

Tags: api, exception, magento, soap-client

I was trying to create a new product but some weird problem happened and it simply gave me this error:

```
Invalid data given. Details in error message.
```

Which was generated by $e -> getMessage() from this snippet:

```
try {
    $result = $proxy -> call($sessionId, $api, $parameters);
    return $result;
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo '<p style="color:red;">'.$e -> getMessage().'</p>';
    return false;
}
```

So where is this "error message"? Thanks!

Comment: try to print_r the $result, without try catch :) or check Mage log files

Comment: Wouldn't removing the `try catch` prevent the code for printing from being executed, anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Magento log files and reports are placed in the `var/` sub directories, these are :

> {Mage_path}/var/log
>   {Mage_path}/var/report

Also check if the configuration is set to output messages in log files ( in System / Configuration / Developer ).

Comment: Unfortunately the message in the Magento log was just about as useless as the one returned by the Exception in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Highly recommend TechColins approach for logging all API calls and responses:

[Magento API performance issues when doing bulk product updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918050/magento-api-performance-issues-when-doing-bulk-product-updates/8616858#8616858)

http://techcolin.net/2011/11/a-php-proxy-script-for-logging-magento-api-soap-calls/

It will enable you to see exactly what's getting passed to the API and the error magento responds with.

Might seem a bit of extra overhead if you're just looking for a quick fix right now, but will be of massive benefit for diagnosing future issues.